# perl encode_base64 versus Redhat base64 command

Tags: shell, perl, base64

I can't seem to figure out why there is a difference:

```
-bash-4.1$ echo "changeit" | base64
Y2hhbmdlaXQK

Versus perl:
use MIME::Base64 qw(encode_base64);
my $encode = encode_base64("changeit","");
print "encode: $encode\n";

Perl outputs:
encode: Y2hhbmdlaXQ=

Why are they different?
```

Comment: What is odd is if I use this method: perl -MMIME::Base64=encode_base64 -e 'print encode_base64 join"",<>' test.txt  and put changeit in the test.txt file it returns the same as the Redhat base64 command.

Comment: If I put either in decode_base64 they both come back with changeit.  It is just that what will decode it is not going to be perl, so I am not sure it will decode as expected.

Answer (score 4):

It's the same as the difference between

```
my $encode = encode_base64("changeit",""); # Y2hhbmdlaXQ=
```

and

```
my $encode = encode_base64("changeit\n",""); # Y2hhbmdlaXQK
```

Try

```
echo -n "changeit" | base64
```

for a fair comparison with Perl.

Comment: Gez, I wonder which I should use then?  Do I do your second encode_base64 that tacks on the newline so it matches echo without the use of -n or just what I had.  I wonder how the decoding will work.  It is for kubernetes by the way.  I guess I will just have to test and see if it falls over or not with one way or the other.